# Parameter inside a method for javascript

Tags: methods, parameters

```
function exerciseOne(){
  // Exercise One: In this exercise you are given an object called 'mathHelpers'
  // Within mathHelpers, create a method called 'double'
  // This method should take one parameter, a number, 
  // and it should return that number multiplied by two.
  let mathHelpers = {
    // Create double method in here.
    double: function(myNumber){
      myNumber * 2;
    }
  };
  return mathHelpers;
}
```

It's coming back it's incorrect. Been stuck on this for 90 mins. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code prior to me working on it

```
function exerciseOne(){
  // Exercise One: In this exercise you are given an object called 'mathHelpers'
  // Within mathHelpers, create a method called 'double'
  // This method should take one parameter, a number, 
  // and it should return that number multiplied by two.
  let mathHelpers = {
    // Create double method in here.

  };
  return mathHelpers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured thanks anyways lol

```
function exerciseOne(){
  // Exercise One: In this exercise you are given an object called 'mathHelpers'
  // Within mathHelpers, create a method called 'double'
  // This method should take one parameter, a number, 
  // and it should return that number multiplied by two.
  let mathHelpers = {
    // Create double method in here.
    double: function(myNumber = 4){
      return myNumber * 2;
    }
  };
  return mathHelpers;
}
```